# Error making table in Latex (Overleaf)

Tags: tables

I want to make a big table in Overleaf, but I keep getting error and not showing the compile output. Here's my code. I wonder where I put the mistake. Because I got errors also in every `\begin` command, even in `\begin{document}`, while when I checked it, all already in pair `\begin - \end`

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Chamber workload and cycle time gap comparison ABC and Half-ABC sequence}
\label{result_com}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| M{1.5cm} | M{0.5cm}| M{2cm} | M{1cm} | M{1cm}| M{1cm} | M{1cm} | M{1cm}| M{1cm} |}
\hline
$   w=2, v=1 $    & \multirow{2}{*}{$k$} &  \multirow{2}{*}{Parameters}             & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Average Gap} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Maximum gap} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Minimum Gap} \\ \cline
$   m   $         &                      &                                          &   ABC       & Half-ABC          & ABC        & Half-ABC           & ABC   & Half-ABC \\   \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{1}& $ 2  $ & \multirow{24}{*}{$ p\in [50, 100] , c\in [50, 1000]$}  & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $ \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 5  $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 10 $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 20 $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{2}& $ 2  $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $ \\ \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 5  $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 10 $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 20 $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{3}& $ 2  $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $ \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 5  $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 10 $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 20 $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{4}& $ 2  $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $ \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 5  $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 10 $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 20 $ &                                                        & $ 0\% $     & $ 0\% $           & $ 0      $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{5}& $ 2  $ &                                                        & $ 0.012\% $ & $ 0\% $           & $ 1.258  $ & $ 0     $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $ \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 5  $ &                                                        & $ 0.129\% $ & $ 0.088\% $       & $ 5.247  $ & $ 6.173 $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 10 $ &                                                        & $ 0.234\% $ & $ 0.205\% $       & $ 7.012  $ & $ 7.513 $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 20 $ &                                                        & $ 0.331\% $ & $ 0.313\% $       & $ 8.007  $ & $ 8.268 $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{6}& $ 2  $ &                                                        & $ 0.411\% $ & $ 0.008\% $       & $ 8.805  $ & $ 3.145 $          & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $ \\ \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 5  $ &                                                        & $ 1.547\% $ & $ 0.943\% $       & $ 20.062 $ & $ 20.988 $         & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 10 $ &                                                        & $ 2.479\% $ & $ 2.05\%  $       & $ 25.042 $ & $ 25.543 $         & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \cline{3-9}
                 & $ 20 $ &                                                        & $ 3.338\% $ & $ 3.067\% $       & $ 27.85  $ & $ 28.111 $         & $ 0 $ & $ 0 $  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  We'll be much more able to help with a compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  If you get an error for `\begin{document}` that means a fatal error was detected before that.  If you have `.aux` files, delete them and try again.  Do you still get an error for `\begin{document}`?  Tell us exactly what the error is.  Also, how you are compiling -- post the first few lines of the error log.  That should give us a good start.

Answer (score 4):

- Error is caused by wrong use of the first `\cline` command in your table. You forgot to declare columns in which it should be drown, i.e. instead of `\cline` it probably should be `\cline{4-9}`.
- This error is independent from Overleaf as well from LaTeX3 (so I delete those tags).
- I suspect, that your table has other issues too, but I can't test it since you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example and therefore is unknown, how is column type `M{...}` is defined and why you use it, etc.
- From table code I guess that `clines` are not adequate determined.
- Possible result of your table, after correcting of error and guessing how `M` columns are defined can be:

[image]

Corrected MWE I would provide when you will extend showed code fragment to MWE.